# Argument Labels (_:, destination) do not match available overloads

Tags: swift, swift3, alamofire

I am trying to migrate my code from Swift 2 to Swift 3. 
This is my code for Resume Data using Alamofire:

```
public func download(resumeData: NSData, destination: Request.DownloadFileDestination) -> Request {
    return download(.ResumeData(resumeData), destination: destination)
}
```

On build it shows the error as:

> Argument Labels (_:, destination) do not match available overloads

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this correct migration for swift 3.0

```
        let destination = DownloadRequest.suggestedDownloadDestination(for: .documentDirectory)

        Alamofire.download(resumingWith: Data, to: destination)
```